# PHP next second friday relative to current date

Tags: php, date, cron

I have a cron job and runs every second Friday to dispatch to a mailing list

```
0   8   *   *   5   test $(($(date +\%V)\%2)) -eq 1
```

How would I find out the next dispatch date relative to the current date in php so I can inform the user when the next dispatch is going to be.

e.g

```
@returns next second Friday date from random_date
function next_dispatch_date(random_date){
} 
echo "Next Dispatch on" . next_dispatch_date(date());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first solution that came into my mind was this:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->modify('next friday'); // Next friday from now
$dt->modify('next friday'); // Next friday from next friday

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

or, as the function hinted at in your post:

```
function next_dispatch_date($timestamp){
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $dt->setTimestamp($timestamp);
    $dt->modify('next friday');
    $dt->modify('next friday');

    return $dt->format('Y-m-d');
}

echo "Next dispatch on ".next_dispatch_date(time());
```

Please note, compared to your original post, that I used `time()` and not `date()`, which is used for formatting timestamps.

Comment: You can also use this: `$dt->modify('this friday + 2 weeks')`. Makse it simpler.

Comment: @awons Yes, this saves a line, but it depends what is requested. On a day before Friday, this would actually give us the third Friday from now.

Comment: Thanks guys looks like I need to brush up on dates in php. I used    $dt->modify('next friday + 1 weeks')  to get the correct date 2015-05-01

Comment: @jeromegamez Not really. `'this tuesday + 2 weeks'` gives `2015-05-05` providaed today is `2015-04-20`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strtotime()` with relative format (see [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php))

i.e.

```
@returns next second Friday date from random_date
function next_dispatch_date($random_date){
  date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Friday next week '.$random_date));
}
```

assuming `$random_date` is in format 'Y-m-d'...

Comment: And even the very same documentations says to avoid strtotime when doing math with dates.